# Is a mySQL or mongoDB relational database scalable for holding 80 GBs of additional logs per day?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am currently deciding on a long term architecture solution for storing DNS logs. The amount of data we are talking about numbers some 80 GBs of logs per day at the peak. Currently I am looking at noSQL databases such as mongoDB, as well as relational - mySQL. I want to structure a solution that has three requirements:

- Storage: This is a long term project, so I want the necessary capability to store 80 GBs of logs per day (~30 TB a year!). I realize this is pretty ridiculous, so I'm willing to have a retention period (keep 6 months' worth of logs = 15 TB constant).
- Scalability: As it is a long term solution, this is a big issue. I've heard that mongoDB is horizontally scalable, while mySQL is not? Any elaboration on this would be very well received.
- Query speed: As close to instantaneous querying as possible.

It should be noted that our logs are stored on an intermediary server, so we do not need to forward logs from our dns servers.

Comment: How are you creating those logs?

If you insert a bunch of information at once, I would suggest pointing to files at S3. Then your database only deals with inserts, and logs go straight from drive to S3. I'm thinking about log rotation here, by the way.

Comment: By the way, as for the initial idea: MongoDB with sharding. Not really my specialty, but if you split your data through a dozen servers you are handling 1/12th of the data on each server. Math is not perfect, especially as you have to consider stuff like unique ids and generating timestamps properly so as to not "mess up" the data, but can be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL can handle at least some aspects of such.

At 15TB, disk I/O is the number one problem!  Both on `INSERT` and `SELECT`.

Indexes are BTree structured.  This gives "close to instantaneous" fetching of one row, given the index.  It also gives rapid scanning in the BTree order, forward or backward.

You can have multiple *unrelated* indexes, but it is problematical.  Indexes are kept up to date as rows are inserted.  This is not the least bit of a problem if the indexes fit in cache.  And not much of a problem when the indexes are somewhat bigger than cache.  The problem comes when an index is much bigger than can be cached in RAM, and the next insert needs to update some spot in the BTree that is not currently cached.  `INSERT`ing slows to disk speed -- perhaps 10s of millions of rows inserted per day.  (This is regardless of `LOAD DATA`, batched INSERTs, staging tables, etc.)

So, you can't have all the indexes you may want.  And without indexes, forget about "close to instantaneous".

So, what to do?  I suggest you turn the design around -- What do you want *out* of this project?  That is, put aside the discussion of size and storage; instead think about what `SELECT`s you would like.  Then think about how to arrange the data to minimize I/O.  Would you like to present some of the SELECTs for discussion?

I will probably push you toward summarizing the data as it comes in, storing the summaries in tables, and tossing the raw data (or at least not storing it in a database).

Two further notes:

Tokudb is excellent at ingesting indexed data -- it can generally do it faster than the standard "engines" in MyISAM.  MariaDB has Tokudb built in.

For purging the data, see [my blog on such](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for sharing your thoughts. I guess I would add to my question: would this fit a noSQL model with MongoDB better? In terms of Selects, in DNS logs for example, there are about 10 columns per entry. The most used selects would be: "SELECT [IPs] WHERE hostname = google.com" or such. I don't see the selects being too complicated ,as there are 10 columns, but 2 or 3 (hostname, IP, data) are central. Another example is "SELET [hostnames] WHERE IP = 172.54.54.10

Comment: I don't know enough about NoSQLs, but the issue of being I/O-bound is a problem regardless.

Comment: For `SELECT [IPs] WHERE hostname = `google.com'`, it seems better to populate a table of only a few MB that contains a mapping of IP and domain.  This could be programmatically populated as you ingest the logs.

Comment: For that, I would write a perl script to grab a thousand rows, dedup, then build a batch `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`.  Or, perhaps simply `INSERT IGNORE ...`.

Comment: I see, so what you are saying is that instead of have one table with 10 columns, which would have multiple rows with the same IP and domain because of different logs, it would be more efficient to have smaller tables, one being a map of IP and domain. However, wouldn't I be "losing" data in a sense? Sure, this answers the question of finding out what IPs are associated with domain names and vice versa, but how would a user inspect this relationship further with the other 8 columns?

Comment: Oops, maybe I misunderstood you.  I thought you wanted a mapping between IP and host.  Looks like you want "all the history for one IP", or "for one host"?  That gets into the problem of multiple indexes and caching issues.  (No, I don't like having lots of similar tables.  10K tables has _other_ problems.)

Comment: I see, well thanks Rick, you've given me a lot to think about.

Comment: I enjoy tackling huge databases.  I try to warn newcomers to "huge" of the pitfalls that are all too likely to occur.  Feel free to bounce more ideas off me.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me more about common pitfalls? Right now I am most likely just going to go with the one huge table of 10 columns. For 15 TB, do you think one powerful machine would be able to pull this off reasonably?

Comment: 15TB/6mo ~= 1000 rows inserted per second.  That's impossible on spinning drives if you have any non-trivial index (such as ip or host).  Can you get 15TB of SSDs?  Will there be 1M rows with 'google.com'?  If so, that will take minutes to read; what processing will do you do on the result?

Comment: Normalization and other techniques to shrink the dataset size are important -- smaller -> more cacheable -> less I/O --> faster. ` PARTITION BY RANGE(<truncate to week>)` is necessary since you will purge.

Comment: Inserting 1000 rows per second requires some amount of coding care.  Since there are many possible approaches, can you provide some details?  One/multiple threads?  Can you gather up rows before doing INSERT or LOAD?  Do the normalization/cleansing/etc before inserting.

Comment: Thanks for your input Rick, it seems you are way ahead of me. I am going to focus on normalizing/cleaning my data before just blindly inserting everything.

Comment: Yes (for your focus)!  You will thank yourself for that.